# RedShift Order of Operations Affecting Results

Tags: sql, math, amazon-redshift

In RedShift, when performing a multiplication/division inside the function, the order of operations is affecting results.

```
select cast((52*100/100) as decimal(4,1)); -- Correctly returns 52.0
select cast((52/100*100) as decimal(4,1)); -- Incorrectly returns 0.0
```

I would expect RedShift to evaluate the brackets first using BEDMAS, whether it is `case 1: 100/100=1*52=52` or `case 2: 52/100=0.52*100=52`. I have tried this with other operations as well as RedShift: TRUNC, ROUND, etc. and they all do the same thing.

Why would the second one result in 0.0?

Comment: Quick way to get what you want is cast the denominator to a float or a decimal first, e.g. `SELECT 52/cast(100*100 as decimal(4,1))` or just add a decimal point and a zero so that it is not an integer-literal e.g. something like `SELECT 52/100*100.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct.  `/` is [integer division](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-math.html):

> **/**     **division (integer division truncates results)**

```
select cast((52.0/100*100) as decimal(4,1));   -- making 52 as 52.0
-- 52.0
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7686031a18669cade373d614c8dfdc33)**

First case:

```
52*100/100 => 5200 / 100 => 52
```

Second case:

```
52/100*100 => 0 * 100 => 0
```

Comment: This is true in all languages.